# Is this a case I would handle in a "type resolution" pass?

Tags: types, compiler-construction, type-resolution

I'm writing a compiler for a simple c-like language. I'm trying to do analysis for the following example:

```
struct Foo {
    char* name;
};
struct Foo foo;
char* blah = foo.name;
```

Specifically, this analysis will handle if `foo` is unresolved, or if `name` is unresolved, etc.
The two ways I approach this is with name resolution, i.e. making sure that `foo` exists, and `name` exists in `foo`. Then there is 'type resolution', which is where I make sure that the `Foo` structure exists.

First question:

- Am I getting this right that the type resolution pass would check if the "Foo" structure exists?

I ask this because I have a slight issue with this approach. Because name resolution is done before type resolution, we can't check `foo.name` because the structure `Foo` has not been resolved yet, so we know nothing about the type, it's fields, their types, etc.

If this is a case that is handled in type resolution:

- Do I do type resolution before or after name resolution?

If I do name resolution *before* type resolution:

- How do I approach my problem where I need to know about the type in name resolution?

Answer (score 1):

An approach I've taken in the past is to merge type resolution with scope resolution into a single pass.

You'll need to build up two environments/tables (one with types and one with names).

so at `char* blah = foo.name`, you'd have `foo` in your name table with a type of `Foo`, in your type table, you'd have `Foo` as a struct with field `name`. Then you can check that your field access `foo.name` is valid (which means both that `foo` is declared and `foo` has a type with `.name` as a field).